# Are there any theoretical limitations to the instantaneous gain or loss of energy?

Tags: energy

I am currently reading an electrical circuit textbook which states that energy can only be extracted or injected in a finite time. Within the physical limitations of a real circuit, I do understand how this is clearly the case. But is there a law which states that energy cannot change instantaneously?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But, $\Delta E = P\Delta t$, where $P$ is power. If the power is finite and $\Delta E$ is finite then $\Delta t = \frac{\Delta E}{P}$ is finite. As an EE example, if $P=IV$ and $I$ is finite and $V$ is finite then so is $P$.

Comment: Relativity limits the speed at which electromagnetic waves can move. The "fastest" circuits are therefor always using vacuum fields. The power in ultrashort laser pulses, for instance, is amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power is defined as a change in energy divided by the time over which that change occurs ($P = \Delta E/\Delta t)$. An instantaneous change in energy results in a division by zero, meaning that the change was caused by something with undefined power. If something can cause some finite energy change in literally zero time, it has undefined power and can cause *literally any* energy change in zero time. An instantaneous change in energy implies a capacity to do *limitless work*, which seems to violate the conservation of energy - it implies that a undefined-power process that results in a change in energy could result in *any* arbitrary change of energy, and not a specific change of energy equal to the input.

As an example, suppose I have a typical machine that takes some input energy (gasoline, electricity, whatever) and can output 100W of power, meaning it can perform 100J of work every second. Now suppose I have a magic machine that also runs on some fuel, but can output an undefined amount of power, meaning it can perform 100J of work in 0 seconds. This machine can also perform 1kJ of work in 0 seconds, or 1MJ, or 1GJ of work in 0 seconds, even though we haven't changed anything about the fuel it runs on. For some fixed input, we get arbitrary output, which is violates the conservation of energy.